# Получение SamAccountName из файла csv

Tags: powershell

У меня имеется мой рабочий скрипт

```
    Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Script\fi13.04.20.csv" | ForEach-Object {

    Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeid -like '*$($_.employeeid)*'"  -Properties employeeid | select employeeid,name,SamAccountName

} | Export-CSV "$home\desktop\Script\fi-san-out.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Я даю ему файл с employeeid и получаю обратно файл с определенными параметрами.

А это улучшенная версия-

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Script\fi13.04.20.csv"

$csvOutput = "$home\desktop\Script\fi-san-out.csv"

$object = @()

foreach($employee in $csv){

    $ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" -Properties samAccountName, displayName ,employeeID  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($ADUserObject){

        $object += New-Object psobject -Property @{

            displayName = $ADUserObject.displayName

            samAccountName = $ADUserObject.SamAccountName

            employeeID = $ADUserObject.employeeID

        }

    }else{

        Write-Host "No employee found for $($employee.employeeId)" -ForegroundColor Red

    }

}

if($object){

    $object | Select-Object displayName, samAccountName, employeeID | Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Первая версия выдает намного больше результатов так как если в ID есть ошибка "к примеру ID в csv 12345 а в AD 123456" он да выдает результат.
В улучшенной версии он выдает ошибку при любом неточном ID.
Вопрос заключается в следушем как изменить улучшенную версию чтобы он выдавал результат даже с ошибкой?
Я только начинаю освоение PS и улучшенную версию писал с помошью друга.

Comment: в строке `$ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" -Properties samAccountName, displayName ,employeeID  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` замените `-eq` на `-like` и поставьте `*` так `'*$($employee.employeeID)*'`

Comment: поведение `*` я думаю очевидно, в случае ID 1234, смогут выбраться записи типа `...01234 ...012345... 12345... 1234`

Comment: Большое спасибо!